# Swift/ iOS: Page view controller and touch events. How to keep superview handle the gesture?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller, hittest

I need to reproduce a city mapper like component : 
[scrollable cards at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENBgG.jpg)

The cards are paging enabled and can be scrolled vertically and each card can have different height. If I touch a card and scrolling right/left I should go to the next/previous card.

The map (in my case it would be a collection view controller) must remain user interaction enabled = true

How would you reproduce such a component ?

My first guess would be to add a UIPageViewController which will be the size of the screen and I will add UIViewControllers in it. Those viewControllers will contain the cards maybe as a tableviewCell in a tableView.
But how to keep the map area handling the gestures ?

Comment: “a UIPageViewController which will be the size of the screen” Why? Why isn’t it the size of the card?

Comment: Humm, because the cards can have different sizes and they can scroll vertically. 
Do you suggest to update the size of the UIPageViewController dynamically based on the card size currently displayed ?